# Non-negative matrix factorization with a regularization term

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given a matrix $X_{M*N}$ with non negative values, I would like to factorize it into $U_{M*K} , V_{N*K}$, where both of them have also non-negative values. Additionally I would like to have a minimum induced 2-norm for $V$. So now the questions is optimizing the following cost function

$O=\|X-UV^T\|_F^2+\|V\|_2^2$

Comment: what is varied?

Comment: This norm doesn't have any good algebraic expressions (without additional hypthesis on $X$) in general case. Essentially, the analytical expression for that norm is finding the eigenvalues of $X^TX$ and choosing maximum of their absolute values. If $K\ge 5$, then we don't have algebraic expressions for roots of the polynomial of degree $K$.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is known as a *non-negative matrix factorization* problem (in fact, I've offered a title edit above to better introduce the question to other Math.SE readers). There is no one "right" way to do this, because the problem is not convex and therefore there are no known tractable algorithms.

One common approach is to alternate between minimizing over $U$ and minimizing over $V$ until no progress is made. Fixing $U$ or $V$ turns the model into a convex minimization with non-negativity constraints. EDIT: I originally misread the regularization term as $\|V\|_F^2$, which is quadratic. But in fact, $\|V\|_2^2$ is still convex, and can be handled by any solver that supports semidefinite constraints.

[Here](http://cvxr.com/cvx/examples/html/nonneg_matrix_fact.html) is some example MATLAB code, using [CVX](http://cvxr.com) (disclaimer: I wrote this), that computes a non-negative matrix factorization without the additional $\|V\|_2^2$ regularization. It could certainly be modified to suit your purposes. The additional term in CVX would be `square_pos(norm(V))`. It is certainly not necessary to use CVX to solve this problem, however.

Again, there is no one approach here that is guaranteed to work well. You would do well to conduct a literature search. Even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) has a good introduction here.

Comment: Yes, This is true. But in my problem I also would like to minimize the induced 2-norm of $V$. Therefore, I am looking for a kind of algebraic approximation for that.

Comment: I've expanded on that above. It's possible someone else in the literature has done this regularization (indeed, it's likely), but you're probably just going to have to roll your own.